# callback function pointer with argument in C language

Tags: c, syntax, callback

I have the following working code in C language, func1 and func2:

```
    void func1(int (*callbackf)(void *, void *)){
        void a = NULL;
        void b=NULL;
        //do some work and then call comp
        callbackf (a,b)
    }
    void func2(int (*callbackf)(void *), void *a, void *b){
        // do some work, not necessary works on a and b.
        callbackf(a,b);
    }
```

I am writing here to ask you if it is possible to do something like this (func3)

```
void func3(int (*callbackf)(void *), void *a, void *b){
        // do some work, not necessary works on a and b.
        callbackf(a,b);
    }
```

is it possible? does it make sense?

regards
Alex

Comment: Besides the fact that `void a = NULL` won't work, what are you trying to do here? `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are basically doing the same thing. Moreover, `int (*callbackf)(void *)` is incorrect as `callback` accepts two parameters.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `void` variable, only `void*`.

Comment: You wrote "*I have the following working code in C language*". This code does not even compile, so how can it be working? Please [edit] your question and copy&paste exactly the working code, don't re-type it. `func3` is the same as `func2`. Assuming that `func2` would be working code, which isn't true, then it would of course be possible to implement a copy of `func2` named `func3`, but it does not make sense to implement the same function twice with different names.